# Pattern matching for finding siblings

Tags: python, string, string-matching

Consider this scenario were I have some sequence number in form of list of String, where a dot represent a level of tree.

I want to find the count of siblings of every sequence number. I tried and below is my code

```
list = ["33.1", "33.5", "33.15", "33.1.1", "33.1.2", "33.1.11", "34.5", "33.2.9"] 

for item in list:
    numberOfSiblings = 0
    splitText = item.rsplit(".", 1)
    
    j = 0
    while( j < len(list)):
        if( list[j].startswith(splitText[0]) and len(item) == len(list[j]) and item != list[j] ):
            numberOfSiblings +=1
        j+=1
    
    print(numberOfSiblings)
```

Here according to items in list..starting at zero index.. "33.1" will have sibling "33.5" and "33.15". (Note : "34.5" will not be counted as it does not start with "33") , so count will be 2. Similarly count of siblings for "33.5" and "33.15" will be 2 also.

Moving at index 3, element "33.1.1" will have siblings "33.1.2" and "33.1.11" only and so on for rest of the items accordingly.

Output should be like:

element =>  No.Of.Siblings

```
33.1 => 2  
33.5 => 2  
33.15 => 2  
33.1.1 => 2  
33.1.2 => 2  
33.1.11 => 2  
34.5 => 0  
33.2.9 => 0
```

Here problem is with the length check in while block. Please help to implement this scenario..Thanks in advance

Comment: 33.1 has three siblings, unless I totally misunderstood what a sibling is

Comment: @MadPhysicist which ones?

Comment: 33.1 can't be sibling of its own. its siblings are 33.5 and 33.15

Comment: What about 33.2?

Comment: yes 33.2 will be sibling. Sorry I misinterpreted it.

Comment: @MasoomRaza question was about `33.2`, not `32.2`

Comment: @MasoomRaza. I suggest you read your own question carefully...

Comment: Does the relationship end at the lowest level? I mean I should drop the last `.number` from each item in list and then check how many of these type of patterns there are in the list?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the list does not contain `33.2` though, only `33.2.9`

Comment: edited my question..sorry for confusion...got my answer by the way..thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is split each 2 strings into separate parts, and compare all parts piece by piece except the last one element (which can differ)

```
l = ["33.1", "33.5", "33.15", "33.1.1", "33.1.2", "33.1.11", "34.5", "33.2.9"] 

for item in l:
    numberOfSiblings = 0
    splitText = item.split(".")
    for otherItem in l:
        otherSplitText = otherItem.split(".")
        if item != otherItem and len(splitText)==len(otherSplitText) and all(a == b for a, b in zip(splitText[:-1], otherSplitText[:-1])):
            numberOfSiblings += 1
    print(f"{item} {numberOfSiblings}")
```

EDIT:
Added O(n) solution based on Counter

```
from collections import Counter

l = ["33.1", "33.5", "33.15", "33.1.1", "33.1.2", "33.1.11", "34.5", "33.2.9"] 
c = Counter()
for item in l:
    head, tail = item.rsplit(".", 1)
    c[head] += 1

for item in l:
    head, tail = item.rsplit(".", 1)
    print(f"{item} {c[head] - 1}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working for now..will test this thoroughly

Comment: @MasoomRaza I've added O(n) solution as well

Answer (score 1):

Since you consider the sibling to end at the last dot we can remove the last number of each string and count how many of them appear in the same list after the removal of the last digit.
Remove `1` because of the self count.

This approach uses `O(n^2)` complexity.

```
lst = ["33.1", "33.5", "33.15", "33.1.1", "33.1.2", "33.1.11", "34.5", "33.2.9"] 
d_s = ['.'.join(x.split('.')[:-1]) for x in lst]
d = {i:0 for i in lst}
for item in d:
    d[item] = d_s.count('.'.join(item.split('.')[:-1])) - 1

d
```

```
{'33.1': 2,
 '33.5': 2,
 '33.15': 2,
 '33.1.1': 2,
 '33.1.2': 2,
 '33.1.11': 2,
 '34.5': 0,
 '33.2.9': 0}
```

Comment: Are you certain about that O(n)? count has O(n) complexity and it's performed in a loop on n elements, giving us O(n^2)